# Cipher acts differently on Android and Windows

Tags: android, encryption

I've got a small windows app that  decrypts a simple message using a RSA algorithem, but got problems achiving the same on Android, looks like I've got a Cipher issue.

on windows I do;

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,_clientPrivateKey);
byte [] r = c..doFinal(encrypted);
```

on Android I've tried with the default "RSA" cipher but also "RSA/None/NoPadding","BC"

Made sure that the _clientPrivateKey bytes are identical on both platforms, but noticed that on windows the type of the key is resolved to sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl while on android it resolves to OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey.

The doFnal result differs on the two platforms, comming out correct on windows.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Thats because the windows standard oracle vm uses the US Law conform Oracle Security Provider with very poor defaults.

Android uses in actual version the OpenSSL Security Provider and before that the BounceCastle Security provider.

Both impl. have different defaults.

That means that when you get an instance with "RSA" the security provider selected the defaults for RSA encryption.

Provide on both sides android and windows desktop a full configuration string

> "algorithm/mode/padding"

For example:

> RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding

Comment: Thanks for fast response ... this is one of my first encryption projects on Java, sorry for the obvious questions.

Comment: no that's the number 1 mistake every does when using encryption and decryption on different VM impl.

Comment: I'm basically trying to decode a encryypted private key generated by > openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout client-private.key -out client-public.pem

Can't realy find a good way to specify algorithem. Using not-yet-commons-ssl to read the key file into the _clientprivateKey. Any suggestions on algorithm/mode/padding to use